# iOS OpenGL game UI

Tags: ios, user-interface, opengl-es

I've created a simple iPhone game just to digest the `OpenGL ES` main concepts. Now it's time to create game `start menus`. I want to know the best practice in doing that. I've heard that combining `UIKit` with `OpenGL ES` may not be preferred, is that true? Should I create the menus through `OpenGL ES`? Or it's ok use `UIKit`?

Comment: UIKit is encouraged for quite some time now and I suggest you use it.

Comment: You will find on stackoverflow that if you go to the bother of accepting answers given to your previous questions, you may get more response.

Comment: @JohnWoods Thanks for the tip. I am just new & didn't know I need to `accept` answers.

Comment: @yassin - no problem, and to your question, I agree with Matic, it's no problem to use UIKit and OpenGL together.